# Bulls and Cows Java code explanation

Tags: java

I've been searching for the source code of this game and found this one. However, I didn't understand the `hasDupes` method at the end of the code.

Could you explain it to me?

Source code - [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bulls_and_cows#Java)

```
public static boolean hasDupes(int num){
    boolean[] digs = new boolean[10];
    while(num > 0){
        if(digs[num%10]) return true;
        digs[num%10] = true;
        num/= 10;
    }
    return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a pen & paper test. Our number system has 10 digits: 0 to 9. `digs` represents, whether a digit has occured already. with `num % 10` you get the last digit of `num`. So let's say `num` has an `1` at the least significant position. That means: `digs[i]` will be set to `true` (`digs[num%10] = true;`). Now let's look on: with `num /= 10` you **remove** the last digit from an integer. For example, `3211 /= 10` will be `321` (integer arithmetics, I know you cannot apply `/=` to literals, but it is only a demonstration to explain the semantics). Since `num` is `> 0`, the loop is executed again. This time, the `if`-condition will be `true` (because we set `digs[1]` to `true` one iteration before), we found a duplicate digit. If the method is able to leave the loop without entering the `if`, `num` has pairwise unequal digits. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the game, it basically checks to see if the given integer, `num`, has duplicated digits. It does so by creating an array of 10 boolean values, such that two digits that are duplicated will be dropped into the same cell in the array. The algorithm uses

1. An array of 10 boolean values to represent each digit in our base 10 number system. So if you are dealing with base 16 number system, you will need an array of 16 boolean values.
2. `num modulo 10` to extract the least significant digit of `num` until all digits have been examined. Again, it uses modulo 10 because it is assuming a base 10 number system.

The moment that duplicated digits are detected, the method returns `true`:

```
if(digs[num%10]) return true;
```

If you look at the `main()` method in your sample codes, the algorithm will attempt to keep generating random number, until one with no duplicated digits is found.

```
while(hasDupes(target= (gen.nextInt(9000) + 1000)));
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's step through it:

```
boolean[] digs = new boolean[10];
```

In Java, all the items in an array declaration are given a default value.  In the case of `boolean`, it is `false`.  So this creates an array of 10 elements where each element is `false`

```
while(num > 0){
    if(digs[num%10]) return true;
    digs[num%10] = true;
    num/= 10;
}
```

Modding a number by 10 (`num % 10`) and then dividing by 10 (`num/= 10`) is a common way to "pop" off the last digit from a number.  For example,

```
int someNum = "1357";
int lastDigit = mod % 10; // lastDigit is 7
someNum /= 10; // someNum is now 135
```

As you can see, the `7` gets removed.  So the `while` loop is just popping of each digit of `num` until all the digits are processed.  Now, for each digit that is being removed, `digs[num%10] = true;` is simply keeping track of the digits already removed.  By keeping track of these, `if(digs[num%10]) return true;` will return `true` from the method if a digit has already been processed.

So, in much simpler words, this method just checks to see if a number contains more than 1 of the same digit.

```
12345 will return false
12341 will return true
```

Answer (score 0):

It's checking if any value in base 10 has duplicated digits.

So `9019` has duplicated digits (`9`) when written as a decimal value.  `123` does not.